# Backup MySQL tables schemas used in hive

Tags: mysql, hive, hive-metastore

I used to have some tables in `HIVE` but after an incident `HIVE` went down and some new tables erased and old tables went back to a previous schema state.

What I want, is to ask if it is there any option to backup tables' schemas into `MySQL` which stores `HIVE` metastore in order to retrieve them if there occurred any incident again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think easier would be to create a python script and gather all metadata ( DDLs) from hive+ impala and store them in some stable RDB like mySQL or oracle.  If you are looking ofr such solution i can share something

Comment: @KoushikRoy This solution seems ok , can you please tell me more ?